# Im receiving DMARC aggregate reports from strange domains - What does this mean?

Tags: email, authentication, dmarc

I recently published a DMARC record with my domain to try and improve my email delivery to gmail. Everything seems to be going according to plan, except that I am receiving reports from strange places like qq.com and italiaonline.it.

I didn't expect to get reports from places like these and I was wondering if this is normal and acceptable, or if I should avoid unzipping these reports. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

That's what happens, DMARC shows what places may be spoofing using your email addresses.

In your report, if the IP listed is not your IP, then most likely it's someone spoofing with your email addresses.  If it's your IP then either you sent emails to those places or someone has access to your SMTP and is sending mail through it without your knowledge.

Those reports you are getting has all the information in it and they are generally save to open up. If you take a look here you'll see some of the places you'll get [DMARC REPORTS](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/dmarc/) from.

I can confirm I got reports from `mailauth-reports@qq.com` but I haven't got one from `italiaonline.it` yet.

If you want a friendly way to parse the reports try [DMARCIAN](https://dmarcian.com/)